# Jenkins plugin for mercurial cannot find revision

Tags: plugins, mercurial, jenkins, auto-update, revision

My jenkins fails when checking out a particular branch fom a repo I have in bitbucket. It only happens with this repo and this branch as other works perfectly. The error is "unknown revision BRANCHNAME" where branchname is the name of my branch.

I still don't get why the mercurial plugin for jenkins don't use --b (branch) in spite of --rev (revision) when you are configuring a branch. But anyway the following has worked with command line:

- Cloning specifying the branch name
- Cloning specifying the branch name as --rev argument

The mercurial plugin for Jenkins uses the "--rev" when you configure a branch in a strange way. First it clones the branch with --rev and then updates the branch to this revision, and is this moment when it fails.

In fact when I am checked out in this branch and I do "hg branches" this branch is not shown.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your branch name cased correctly? Hg is case sensitive.

Comment: Yes, the branch it is just numbers anyway (1.0.0)